# List with Text and Buttons in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am quite new to Android. And I am working on an App. 
One part of the app should have a view with list: (attached)[image])

I want to implement the same list in android.

The list item sturcture: 
Text | Button1 | Button 2

The button behavior: 
If user clicks the first button (yes button), it just gets selected. 
But when the second button (no button, X), underneath it three other button options appears. I have implemented in JavaScript.

But do not know how to approach it in android.

I am looking for options how I can have similar behavior(open for different design approaches) in android.

What are the best and/or easiest way to do?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

In your layout.xml file, you can set views/widgets/etc... to `android:visibility="invisible"` or `android:visibility="gone"` by default. Then, programmatically in your onclick event, just show/hide them like so:

```
yourElement.setVisibility(View.Visible);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a ListView:

```
String [] items = {"item1", "item2", "item3"...};
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this,  items);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

ListViewAdapter:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item_listview, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_listview, parent, false);
    TextView dateTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem1);
    Button button1 = rowView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = rowView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button button3 = rowView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button button4 = rowView.findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button button5 = rowView.findViewById(R.id.button5);
    LinearLayout linearLayoutFirstButton = rowView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutFirstButton);
    button2.setOnClickListenersetOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()            {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              linearLayoutFirstButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                  
        }

    }
    return rowView;
}
}
```

Your list_item_listview.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3">

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout1"
android:layout_weight="2">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_textview"/>

</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout2"

    android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutFirstButton"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutFirstButton"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Buyer Beware:** Untested code.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. Good to start with something.